# htaccess regex to prevent rouge indexed url's

Tags: .htaccess

looking for a regular expression in my `.htacess` that will allow

http://example.com/index.php or http://example.com/anything-else

but redirect

http://example.com/index.php/anything-else

this is as close as I can come to the proper regex

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /send-them-to-404/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You do not need to use Regex or RewriteRule for this. Url part after a filename is part of `AcceptPathInfo` directive.  You simply need to  Use  `AcceptPathInfo Off` in htacess .  Off status will return a 404 error if a filename with traling  path is requested

Comment: we need the rouge url's to go to a 410 page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AcceptPathInfo` directive as I already mentioned in comments but if 
urls were indexed by search engines then you need to use a 301 redirect to redirect them to a 404 page. 301 redirect updates previously indexed urls to the new ones.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^.+\.php/.+$ /404.php [L,R=301]
```